# Parse .bpmn file in jBPM

Tags: xml, parsing, jbpm, bpmn

Are there any parsers available to parse xml (.bpmn) file?
I have .bpmn files from processes designed in jBPM. I would like to parse these files and populate the respective objects.

I googled but could not find any lead. 
I also explored the package org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml; but could not find relevant parser.

It would be great if I can parse the xml file, and find out different tasks in process e.t.c.

Any lead would be helpful.

Thanks,